# PyQGIS zoomscale freezes map canvas

Tags: pyqgis, select-by-attribute, zoom, mapcanvas

I have a PyQGIS code made partially with graphical modeler and some personal completion.

Basically, based on this code I want:

1. Type any city from my point shapefile, select it by attribute.
2. Zoom to the point shapefile at a specific scale.

Issue: On the second part of the script, while trying to zoom at a specific scale, the map canvas freezes, trying to zoom in or out does not rescale the map canvas.

Example:

a) 4 cities as example
[image]
b) Selecting a specific city by attribute
[image]
c) Zooming to specific scale (from here starts the issue).
[image]
d) Trying to zoom out it does not render anything else except what it was already rendered.
[image]
This is the first part exported from graphical modeler which works perfecly:

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('cities', 'Cities', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterExpression('city_names', 'City Names', parentLayerParameterName='', defaultValue=''))

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
    feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
    results = {}
    outputs = {}

    # Select by attribute
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD': 'Name',
        'INPUT': parameters['cities'],
        'METHOD': 0,  # creating new selection
        'OPERATOR': 0,  # =
        'VALUE': parameters['city_names']
    }
    outputs['SelectByAttribute'] = processing.run('qgis:selectbyattribute', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
```

This is the second part completed by me (where the issue starts at zoomscale):

```
    iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    canvas_city = iface.mapCanvas()
    area = layer.selectedFeatures()[0]['Area_km2']

    if area > 400:
        canvas_city.zoomScale(100000)
    else:
        canvas_city.zoomScale(50000)

    canvas_city.refresh()
    
    return results

def name(self):
    return 'model'

def displayName(self):
    return 'model'

def group(self):
    return ''

def groupId(self):
    return ''

def createInstance(self):
    return Model()
```

I have also tried inserting the zoom scale values into a variable like this (with no success):

```
    iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    area = layer.selectedFeatures()[0]['Area_km2']
    canvas_city = iface.mapCanvas()
    
    if area > 400:
        scale = 10000
    else:
        scale = 50000
    
    canvas_city.zoomScale(scale)

    # refresh the canvas
    canvas_city.refresh()
    
    return results

def name(self):
    return 'model'

def displayName(self):
    return 'model'

def group(self):
    return ''

def groupId(self):
    return ''

def createInstance(self):
    return Model()
```

Does anyone know if I did something wrong regarding the second part of the code lines, or is a QGIS issue?

Comment: Please read the [Tip given here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#flags) (the paragraph with green background). Interacting with the map canvas from inside the `processAlgorithm()` method is definitely not thread safe. Try re-implementing the `flags()` method and return `QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading`. Not really what it's intended for, but you could also try putting the zooming logic in the [postProcessAlgorithm()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingAlgorithm.html#ac0162e2a5eccc253c5bcd3590010c4e9) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the script by implementing **flags()** and return **QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading** and it works perfectly.

This part of code where flags() was added:

```
    if area > 400:
        scale = 150000
    else:
        scale = 50000
    
    canvas.zoomScale(scale)

    # refresh the canvas
    canvas.refresh()
    
    return results

def flags(self):
    return QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading

def name(self):
    return 'model'

def displayName(self):
    return 'model'

def group(self):
    return ''

def groupId(self):
    return ''

def createInstance(self):
    return Model()

def groupId(self):
    return ''

def createInstance(self):
    return Model()
```